# How to retrieve matched event from Cloudwatch in Codebuild?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-codebuild

Like in lambda, the Cloudwatch events are sent to handler(event, context), if I set Codebuild as target, which variable do I use to read the matched event in Codebuild?

Answer (score 0):

For the AWS CodeBuild target in CloudWatch Events (for example to trigger a build at regular intervals), you can match by projectARN. Details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-codebuild.html

If you are using this integration more as a means of consuming the event stream from CodeBuild for build state and phase chnage, you can follow the sample @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-build-notifications.html